# GenyMotion Error: Unable to start the virtual device. VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device

Tags: android, genymotion

I have attempted to run Genymotion Android emulator by following the [User Guide](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide), but am getting the following error:

> **Unable to start the virtual device.**
>
> VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device.
>
> To find out the cause of the problem, start the virtual device from  VirtualBox.
>
> For more information, check the log files. Please refer to: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=collapse-logs#faq

Can anyone suggest how I can resolve this?

Comment: If you are using `Windows`, restart `PC` and try it again

Comment: on  Mac OS X 10.9.5 System

Comment: What is Virtual Box telling you? "To find out the cause of the problem, start the virtual device from VirtualBox."

Comment: I have try to start virtual device from VirtualBox it gives me error:-Failed to open a session  for the virtual machine(Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).)

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8410

Comment: Thank you Christopher.Its  help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Enter to BIOS and look for an option named "Intel Virtualization Technology", "Intel VT-x", "Virtualization Extensions", "Vanderpool" or something similar. Enable the option and select “Save and Exit” or the equivalent feature to save your settings changes and reboot your computer.

[How to Enable Intel VT-x in Your Computer’s BIOS or UEFI Firmware](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to forget Genymotion and VirtualBoxas they are very bad. Download Droid4x it is very easy to test apps with.

One thing to do when you download and install it, is to go to Settings -> Developer Tool Debuging and turn it on.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

*Change the virtualBox  to **4.3.12***

Delete the virtualBox and download from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3_pre24
choose 4.3.12

my computer is windows7 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Really old question** but to solve it you can try to [download VirtualBox latest version](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

It solved the problem for me already twice. First time when I first downloaded GenyMotion that came with an old incompatible version of VirtualBox. After a couple of months the problem appeared in GenyMotion again and a VirtualBox upgrade solved it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because either you have changed the Virtualbox host-only settings or have completely deleted the Virtualbox host-only in the network connection window.
To fix this, just uninstall the virtualbox and genymotion once and install Virtualbox and Virtualbox sdk first, and then install genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this issue and  updated the virtual box latest version and everything works now.

Answer (score -1):

1. Goto Network Settings >>
2. Select Adapter settings >>
3. open VirtualBox properties >>
4. **Enable Virtualbox networking Driver** >>
5. Okay.